# How to make bot respond unknown command if bot doesn't recognize command (command handler) discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make it so if someone does something like &hep or &asdsw it will say unknown command since there is no command that matches what the user typed in. Basically the same unknown command thing. I saw another post, but that wasn't for command handlers. I have no code written out. Thanks!

Comment: Does your command handler store the commands in a Collection?

Comment: Yes! Basically it just stores the commands!

Answer (score 0):

Since the commands are stored in a Collection, you can use [Collection.get()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) and check if the command exists.

```js
const Collection = new Discord.Collection();

// This part should be already done by your command handler.
Collection.set("commandName", "commandFile");

// Getting the command (assuming the key is the name of the command)
const Command = Collection.get("commandName");
if (!Command) return message.channel.send("The command does not exist.");

// The command exists.
```

Comment: all my commands are stored in a folder called commands.

Comment: I gave you an example of how to get the command from your Collection. (Where your commands are stored).